# iOS - Local notifications - cancelAllLocalNotifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

May be a simple question:
When I call "cancelAllLocalNotifications", does it cancel notifications created by the app only or it will cancel all notifications from other apps also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notifications created by other apps will not be affected.

From: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW13)

> "You can cancel a specific scheduled notification by calling
>   cancelLocalNotification: on the application object, and you can cancel
>   all scheduled notifications by calling cancelAllLocalNotifications."

Although, this is probably not the best written sentence, the "on the application object" applies to cancelAllLocalNotifications as well as cancelLocalNotification.

Hope that helps!