# Does calling UILocalNotification cancelAllLocalNotifications cancel notifications only for the app it is being called from or all notifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uilocalnotification

If I cancel notifications by calling the UILocalNotification's cancelAllLocalNotifications in my app, does it cancel notifications only set by my application or does it cancel all notifications from all apps?

Thanks.

Comment: what a question :) no man just your one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just cancels notifications from your app.

Answer (score 0):

@PixelCloudSt answered it pretty well here:
[iOS - Local notifications - cancelAllLocalNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033690/ios-local-notifications-cancelalllocalnotifications)